# is there a way to stop users sending to unwanted email accounts?

Tags: email, postfix

I want to set a command that only allows users to send emails to accounts ending in

```
@hotmail.com 
@gmail.com
@talktalk.net
```

for example. Is there a way to set it so users can only enter these emails as valid email?

Comment: Are you using a local MTA such as Postfix, or did you configure `sendmail` to use a remote SMTP server?

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over your MTA (e.g. local Postfix), you may use `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to restrict the domains to which emails may be sent.

First, create your whitelist file (let's say, `/etc/postfix/recipient_domains`) :

```
hotmail.com    OK
gmail.com      OK
talktalk.net   OK
```

Generate the hash file for it...

```
$ postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_domains
```

Now edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to add the restriction:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_domains,
    reject
```

And don't forget to restart Postfix.